# Compare intersections between groups specified in first column

Tags: r, set-intersection, cross-product

Lets say I have a dataframe of three columns: The first one specifies the number of a feature (e.g. color), the second one a group and the third one if the feature is present in that group (1) or missing in that group (0):

```
> d<-data.frame(feature=c("red","blue","green","yellow","red","blue","green","yellow"), group=c(rep("a",4),rep("b",4)),is_there=c(0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0))
> d
  feature group is_there
1     red     a        0
2    blue     a        1
3   green     a        1
4  yellow     a        0
5     red     b        1
6    blue     b        1
7   green     b        1
8  yellow     b        0
```

Now I would like to have a summary of how many features are: 1. only in group a, only in group b and how many are in present in both groups. Additionally I need to extract the name of features present in both groups. How can I do that? I imagine that a function like `crossprod` might help, but I cannot figure it out.

The output would be something like:

```
feature 
red     1
blue    2
green   2
yellow  0
```

or:

```
feature a b
red     0 1
blue    1 1
green   1 1
yellow  0 0
```

anyways i need a better overview over a quite big datafile (the original has hundreds of features in about 10 groups).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like a `table` is what you want.  First we subset the rows such that the `is_there` column equals 1 and remove the third column.  Then we call a `table` on that subset.

```
> ( tab <- table(d[d$is_there == 1, -3]) )
#         group
# feature  a b
#   blue   1 1
#   green  1 1
#   red    0 1
#   yellow 0 0
```

A `table` is a matrix-like object. We can operate on it in much the same way we operate on a `matrix`.

Looking at group `a` :

```
> tab[,"a"]                           ## vector of group "a"
#  blue  green    red yellow 
#     1      1      0      0 
> tab[,"a"][ tab[,"a"] > 0 ]          ## present in group "a"
#  blue green 
#     1     1 
> names(tab[,"a"][ tab[,"a"] > 0 ])   ## "feature" present in group "a"
# [1] "blue"  "green"
```

And the same for group `b`.

Comment: This does not show that yellow is not present in any of the two groups? Maybe my question was unprecisely asked.

Comment: @Richard Scriven +1 Your `table` is more cleaner than mine

Comment: @akrun -thanks.  Yours could be made the same by adding back in the names. `table(feature = d$feature[!!d$is_there], group = d$group[!!d$is_there])`. It was dependent on the subset, I guess.

Comment: Oh, gotcha.  Yeah, I had a professor who was obsessed with tables. Haha.

Answer (score 1):

```
 tbl <- table(d$feature[!!d$is_there], d$group[!!d$is_there])
 rowSums(tbl)
 #blue  green    red yellow 
 #  2      2      1      0 

 tbl

 #       a b
 #blue   1 1
 #green  1 1
 #red    0 1
 #yellow 0 0
```

If you wanted to have the groupings like below:

```
  d1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(rep(c("none", "only", "both")[rowSums(tbl)+1],
           each=2), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE, dimnames=dimnames(tbl)),
                                          stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

  d1[!tbl & rowSums(tbl)==1]  <- ""
  d1
 #        a    b
 #blue   both both
 #green  both both
 #red         only
 #yellow none none
```

Comment: @Richard Scriven  I am not sure if this is what the OP wants.  May be it is your solution

Comment: Is the double "!!" different from "!" ?

Comment: @aldorado  It is double negation.  Try `!d$is_there` and `!!d$is_there`

Comment: @aldorado that's a hack to get 1 and 0 translated to TRUE and FALSE. Something `as.logical()` does as well

Answer (score 1):

Try following code:

```
with(d, tapply(is_there, list(feature, group), sum))
#       a b
#blue   1 1
#green  1 1
#red    0 1
#yellow 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

would that do the trick?

```
> tapply(d$feature[d$is_there==1],d$group[d$is_there==1], table)

$a
blue  green    red yellow 
   1      1      0      0 

$b
blue  green    red yellow 
   1      1      1      0
```

Answer (score 0):

Take following data frame:

```
myd <- data.frame(
  feature=c("red","blue","green","yellow","red","blue","green","yellow"),
  group=c(rep("a",4),rep("b",4)),
  is_there=c(0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0))
```

To get a factor telling you where everything is, you can try this code:

```
require(reshape2)

res <- acast(myd,feature ~ group, fun=sum, value.var="is_there")
where <- factor(
  colSums(res) - 2*diff(t(res)),
  levels=c(-1,0,2,3),
  labels=c("group2","nowhere","both","group1")
  )
```

Gives :

```
> res
       a b
blue   1 0
green  1 1
red    0 1
yellow 0 0
> where
   blue   green     red  yellow 
 group1    both  group2 nowhere 
Levels: group2 nowhere both group1
```

Extracting those that are present everywhere is trivial from here.

Note that any of the other solutions giving you the matrix `res` are equally valid (the tapply solution will be faster)

Comment: `tapply` is faster than `table` ?

Comment: @RichardScriven `tapply` is faster than `acast` and `table` gives a different result (as in: not the one you need here)